# Django MYSQL Python Hex characters causing error on data import

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a number of Excel spreadsheets to process into MYSQL using Django. I save as CSV and process files. The problem I am having is the fields have a variety of hex characters in them. I started trying to replace them in python as they came up but it became unworkable.

As an example one field has the character 'Â' in it and when I save the record to MYSQL I get the following error.

Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xC2A sim...' for column 'description' at row 1

I tried changing field type in MYSQL to ucf8_general_ci but it hasn't solved the problem.

I tried playing with unhexlify by running my strings through the reformat_content function below but it also makes no difference.

```
def asciirepl(match):
  # replace the hexadecimal characters with ascii characters
  s = match.group()  
  return binascii.unhexlify(s[2:]) 

def reformat_content(data):
  p = re.compile(r'\\x(\w{2})')
  return p.sub(asciirepl, data)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this across the whole range of hex chars?

Many thanks

Rich